# newsletters responsive for Gmail

Tags: gmail, newsletter, responsiveness

Hi everyone do you have any idea how can I make a responsive newsletter for google Mail my media query has not been recognize when I test It to the phone and in the email trying to figure it out a whole week , , , Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way of apply media query on newsletter:

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

```
table[class=full] {
width:100%!important;}

table td[class=border] {
border-top:1px solid #e5e5e5 !important;
text-align:center !important;
width:33% !important;}

td[class=responsiveimg] img {

width:100% !important;
display:block !important;}
```

}

Here is a demo for your help:
https://jsfiddle.net/0drvLx4m/

Comment: is this compatible for gmail??